# how to maintain spring-boot external configuration for all environment

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, microservices, application.properties

I have external property files in spring boot based project, I am configuring like below.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:${application_home}config.properties") 
@ComponentScan({"com.myorg.project","com.myorg.project.module"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now I have many environments like dev,prod,staging. Like this I am having almost 7 environment.

```
I am maintaining like below

dev-config.properties
prod-config.properties
stg-config.properties
```

So adding any new config parameters becoming tedious task, as developers interested only in adding to dev-config.properties so extending the same to other is becoming problematic also developer may miss adding the same config variable name to other config files.

Is there any way where adding any config variable should be reflected other with default(if any change required will be handled by devops)

Is there anyway maintain what is changing from current release to old release ?

Because of this it is affecting CI-CD also.